# MouseListener on button rendered on a JTree Row in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtree, mouselistener

I'm blocked with a probelm about Java and the use of JTree:

I want to create a JTree with, node by node, some JButtons components (or Images, I don't mind), like in the following picture. It will be 3 or 4 buttons in the same row. I succeed to do that.

[image]

But where I'm blocked is when I want to add a mouselistener on each of this button to manage their tooltip or an action on them. 
In fact the JTree component is most of the time used to manage the action on the full node, but not on its inside components.

I did a short code, in comparaison at the real big code I have to work in, to quickly test what I say:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class TreeWithPopup extends JPanel {

    DefaultMutableTreeNode root, node1, node2, node3;

    public TreeWithPopup() {
        MyJTree tree;
        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root", true);
        node1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("node 1", true);
        node2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("node 2", true);
        node3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("node 3", true);
        root.add(node1);
        node1.add(node2);
        root.add(node3);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        tree = new MyJTree(root);
        tree.setCellRenderer(new PCellRenderer());
        add(new JScrollPane((JTree) tree), "Center");
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tree with button");
        TreeWithPopup panel = new TreeWithPopup();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setForeground(Color.black);
        frame.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, "Center");
        frame.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowCloser());
    }
}

class WindowCloser extends WindowAdapter {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        Window win = e.getWindow();
        win.setVisible(false);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class MyJTree extends JTree implements ActionListener {

    MyJTree(DefaultMutableTreeNode dmtn) {
        super(dmtn);
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("JTree.MouseListener");
            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("JTree.MouseListener");
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("JTree.MouseListener");
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("JTree.MouseListener");
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("JTree.MouseListener");
            }
        });

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println("MyJTree.ActionPerformed");
    }

}

class PCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree ptree, Object pvalue, boolean psel, boolean pexpanded, boolean pleaf, int prow,
            boolean phasFocus) {
        Box myPanel = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);

        JButton myButton = new JButton("test");
        Image imgToUse = null;
        Image imgRollOver = null;
        try {
            URL urlIcon = new URL("file:///C:/1.jpg"); // <===== change their the path to icons
            imgToUse = ImageIO.read(urlIcon);
            urlIcon = new URL("file:///C:/2.jpg"); // <===== change their the path to icons
            imgRollOver = ImageIO.read(urlIcon);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myButton.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(imgRollOver));
        myButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgToUse));
        myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println(" detected on ");
            }
        });

        myButton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("myButton.MouseListener");
            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("myButton.MouseListener");
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("myButton.MouseListener");
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("myButton.MouseListener");
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("myButton.MouseListener");
            }
        });
        myPanel.add(myButton);

        return myPanel;
    }
}
```

You just have to change the icon path or put the two following icons at "c:/"

[image]

[image]

I also searched to use the x/y position of the row event but I was unable to find the position of my button after rendering.

If anyone can have an idea how to do that, he could be very helpful.

Thanks, at least for read this question ;-)

Comment: Tooltip support would be provided directly by renderer.  Set the tooltip text of the component been used by to renderer the tree cell directly

Answer (score 3):

Tooltip support is actually provided by the `TableCellRenderer` directly.  Your `TableCellRenderer` is a little muddled.  It extends from `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` but makes no use of any of it's features, instead creating a new `Box`, `JButton` and loading icons each time a cell is rendered...

This is going to increase your memory usage a slow you application down...

Instead, try something like...

```
class PCellRenderer extends Box implements TreeCellRenderer {

    private Image imgToUse = null;
    private Image imgRollOver = null;

    public PCellRenderer() {
        super(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);

        JButton myButton = new JButton("test");
        try {
            URL urlIcon = new URL("file:///C:/1.jpg"); // <===== change their the path to icons
            imgToUse = ImageIO.read(urlIcon);
            urlIcon = new URL("file:///C:/2.jpg"); // <===== change their the path to icons
            imgRollOver = ImageIO.read(urlIcon);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myButton.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(imgRollOver));
        myButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgToUse));

        add(myButton);
    }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree ptree, Object pvalue, boolean psel, boolean pexpanded, boolean pleaf, int prow,
            boolean phasFocus) {
        // set the tooltip text here...
        // Maybe change the icon...
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now, actually doing something...

Renderers are rubber stamps.  That are not actually life components.  Think of them like photos.  You can take a snap shot of your friends, but you can't interact with them...same thing here...

Your idea of a `MouseListener` on the `JTree` is a correct one, in fact the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) actually have a demonstration of this...

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    int selRow = tree.getRowForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
    TreePath selPath = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if(selRow != -1) {
        if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {
            mySingleClick(selRow, selPath);
        }
        else if(e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            myDoubleClick(selRow, selPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but: the class you suggest to change implmenting TableCellRenderer seems to be used by a JTable, my JTree refuse to use it (the compiler). Moreover, the example get from the JavaDocs is useful, If I don't mistake, to know if you clicked on a row/node or on a white space. In fact I cannot put this code on my button because the action is not launched at all, which is the problem here.

Comment: My bad updated example. The problem is, your button will never fire. The best you can do is determine when a row is clicked and then determine if the click fill within bounds of the cell renderer